# Obj not exporting with texture points

Tags: c++, directx, blender, maya, .obj

Every time I try to export a obj from some 3d model making program it exports without indices for the texture coordinates. I don't want x//xn y//yn z//zn I want x/xn/u y/yn/v z/zn/w. I've tried blender and maya. Maya doesn't have a option for exporting these. But blender will let you choose whether you want to write normals and texture points. How can I get the texture point indices in there?

Comment: I think if you export Materials in Maya, you'll get texture coordinates. Check the little box on the export screen to the right of the file dialog.

Comment: The only options I have are "Default file extension", "Preserve references", "Export unloaded references", "Groups", "Points Groups", "Materials", "Smoothing", "Normals". It's not the texture coordinates I want. It's the indices in the face.

Comment: Won't the .mtl file that gets exported have those? The .obj format doesn't store texture coords IIRC

Comment: no there are 3 different types of indices for .obj. f x//xn y//yn z//zn, f x/xn/u y/yn/v z/zn/w, and f x/u y/v z/w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blendr's site mentions that it can export UVs, did you check that? [Blender's Wavefront OBJ options](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Wavefront_OBJ#Export_Options)

Comment: Yeah recently I used Blender to export them and it worked but since like yesterday it won't export them as x/xn/u y/yn/v z/zn/w. I just keep getting x//xn y//yn z//zn  for the indices. That format won't work with my obj parser.